# Steps for connecting femal-to-female sacrificial adaptor into a male connector in the RF measurement equipment

Tags: rf, measurement, high-frequency, frequency-measurement, test-equipment

First of all, I am a newbie to the RF-mm-wave test equipments. I am trying to use this Agilent equipment shown in the image below where I want to connect a 1.85mm (F-to-F) sacrificial connector to the equipment's 2.4mm male connector. Could someone please guide me on how I should go about safely/properly make this connections? i.e. What steps I should take? For example, what part I should turn and what part I should be holding with the wrench OR hands?

[image: image of equipment with 2.4mm male connector and the small image of the 1.85 mm (F-F) sacrificial adaptor]

Also, once I make the connection, please also let me know on steps to disconnect this connection.

Comment: These are different sizes; you will need an adapter. You could replace your F-to-F with one that also changes 2.4mm-to-1.85mm, like this: https://www.centricrf.com/adapters/1-85mm-adapters/1.85mm-to-2.4mm-adapters/c8131-1.85mm-female-to-2.4mm-female-adapter/

Comment: I thought 2.4mm are compatible with 1.85mm connector? Isn't it.

Comment: Okay, I stand corrected; they do mate.  Usually the F-to-F will have a flat in the center that you can hold

Comment: hmm. so once holding the center of the adapter with hands while gently moving into the equipment's male connector , should I then turn the outer big knob on the equipment to complete the connection?

Comment: I would usually put the bullet (F-to-F) into the outer male connector (e.g. cable) and then tighten that connector onto the equipment.  The bullet will transfer the torque from the outer male to inner male.  So you hold the outer shell on either side, and the adapter is tightened between them.  For lab equipment, usually the connectors are finger tightened to about 5in-lbs.

Comment: ok I see. Since I want to use this bullet (F-to-F) as a sacrificial connector, I want to keep this connected to equipment and then allow user to connect-disconnect the cable as required so, wondering if you got any method to just insert the bullet first into the equipment.

Comment: Yeah, I was just getting to that.  This adapter will not be very good as sacrificial.  It will tend to loosen on the equipment, transferring wear and tear.

Comment: Oh ok. Sorry if this becomes a side question but then what would be a good choice for the sacrificial connector in my case; assume I purchased a 1.85 mm (M) to 2.4mm (F)?

Comment: You could torque the bullet slightly more than finger tight (8-10 in-lb) so that the outer connection breaks first, but that won't be completely reliable as it wears. The F-to-M would provide the male shell that you could hold in place.